# Out of order packet recombination in C

Tags: c, file-transfer

I'm trying to make a C program that receives a file broken up into 64-bit segments and recombines them. The packets will be arriving out of order but have an ID with them (to re-order them)

I've made the file transfer part, but it needs to arrive in order right now.

Not really sure how to approach this. Was thinking of using an array to store the future IDs until needed, but that seems cumbersome and complex with all the dynamic memory allocation.

EDITs: thanks Barmar for the response. That makes sense, but this is happening inside a function that will go out of scope after each packet is sent and I cant save the data to a higher level.

thanks

Comment: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc815

Comment: Do you know the file size ahead of time?  You could just allocate a memory space for the whole thing, or a little more advanced, use mmap to open a window onto the file.  Then just right the packets to the right palcew when they come in.  You might still have to track if you’re missing any packets.    64-bit segments are awfully small though?

Comment: These IDs are sequence-numbers, numbered incrementally?

Comment: You're trying to do something close to what TCP already do. You should read about how this protocol works, it will GREATLY help you.

Comment: Max: I dont know the file size until the end.
wildplasser: yes the IDs are sequental

Comment: I have done this before, even in real time, by preallocating a huge number of nodes for use in a linked list. Upon packet reception I would borrow such a node, and assign it to a stream using a 5-tuple. Then within the stream I would place it at the correct position using the TCP acknowledgement numbers.

Comment: @grant,please provide more details.